# Getting EvaluateException was unhandled - Cannot Find column [CustConActive]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

After doing a recent update to Visual Studio I am now getting this Error when I try to run My Code.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [CustConFullname] FROM [dbo].[ContactTable] WHERE [CustID] = '" + oCustID + "' ORDER BY [CustConFullname] ASC;", conn))
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adpt.Fill(ds);
    contactTableBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //<Exception thrown 
    custConFullnameComboBox.Enabled = true;
    custConFullnameComboBox.DisplayMember = "CustConFullname";
    custConFullnameComboBox.ValueMember = "CustConFullname";
    custConFullnameComboBox.Refresh();
    custConFullnameComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}//End using
```

Once the program starts running it stalls and throws the exception EvaluateException was Unhandled `Cannot Find Column [CustLocActive]`. I am creating a creating a dropdown and only requesting the names, why now after an update is it having a issue?

Comment: Can you post the full exception?

Comment: EvaluateException was unhandled                                     Cannot find column [CustLocActive].                                                   - Get general help for this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that maybe you have changed your database structure (maybe added or deleted a column) and when you perform

```
adpt.Fill(ds);
```

old fill query is submitted to get Data. Go to your Fill definition in the Dataset and be sure that the query is selecting all clumns of the table(CustLocActive).

Comment: The FillBy query was missing the  column name [custlocActive] but it was available in the Fill query. This did the trick.